# Parse XML data - How to build complicated structure?

Tags: swift, xml, struct, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse XML file.

**My project is here:**
https://github.com/Marcel-git666/CzechTV

**XML Sample:**

```
<program datum_vysilani="2023-02-24" kanal="ct24" generovano="2023-02-24 10:25:43">
<porad>
<linky>
<program>http://www.ceskatelevize.cz/porady/15560675929-rok-valky/223411033420224/</program>
<ivysilani>http://www.ceskatelevize.cz/ivysilani/15560675929-rok-valky/223411033420224/</ivysilani>
</linky>
<vps>A24020558</vps>
<datum>2023-02-24</datum>
<cas>05:59</cas>
<nazvy>
<nadtitul/>
<nazev>Rok války</nazev>
<original/>
<nazev_casti/>
</nazvy>
<dil/>
<zanr>Zpravodajství</zanr>
<stopaz>181:00</stopaz>
<noticka>Rok od ruské invaze na Ukrajinu. Rok, který změnil všední život v Česku. Události připomenou zpravodajové přímo ze zdevastované země, ale i Ukrajinci, kteří dočasně našli domov v České republice. Speciální vysílání ČT1 a ČT24</noticka>
<regionalni>N</regionalni>
<alternativa>N</alternativa>
<ikonky>
<zvuk>S</zvuk>
<skryte_titulky>1</skryte_titulky>
<neslysici>0</neslysici>
<ad>0</ad>
<live>0</live>
<premiera>1</premiera>
<cb>0</cb>
<hvezdicka>0</hvezdicka>
<labeling/>
<puvodni_zneni>0</puvodni_zneni>
<pomer>16:9</pomer>
<hd>1</hd>
</ikonky>
<obrazky>
<tv_program>http://img.ceskatelevize.cz/program/porady/15560675929/foto/program.jpg</tv_program>
<nahled>http://img.ceskatelevize.cz/program/porady/15560675929/foto/uni.jpg</nahled>
</obrazky>
<dostupnost>
<stav>ano</stav>
<od/>
<do/>
</dostupnost>
</porad>
<porad>
</program>
```

I know I have adapt several functions in my class Parser:
Most probably this:

```
func parser(
  _ parser: XMLParser,
  didStartElement elementName: String,
  namespaceURI: String?,
  qualifiedName qName: String?,
  attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]
) {
  if (elementName=="article") {
    articleNth += 1
  } else if (elementName=="title") {
    print("'\(elementName)' in the article element number \(articleNth)")
  }
}
```

and

```
func parser(
  _ parser: XMLParser,
  foundCharacters string: String
)
```

I can read XML file from internet:

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published var program: Program = Program.init(porad: [])
  func fetchData() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.ceskatelevize.cz/services-old/programme/xml/schedule.php?user=test&date=27.12.2022&channel=ct24") {
      let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
      let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if error == nil {
          //let decoder = JSONDecoder()
          if data != nil  {
            do {
              let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
              // print(contents)
              let parser = Parser()
              let xmlParser = XMLParser(data: data!)
              xmlParser.delegate = parser
              xmlParser.parse()
            } catch {
              print(error)
            }
          }
        }
      }
      task.resume()
    }
  }
}
```

What I have no idea is how do I populate my struct Program?

```
struct Program: Codable {
  let porad: [Porad]
}

struct Porad: Codable {
  let linky: Linky
  let vps: Int
  let datum: String
  let cas: String
  let nazvy: Nazvy
  let dil: String?
  let zanr: String
  let stopaz: String
  let noticka: String?
  let regionalni: String
  let alternativa: String
  let ikony: Ikony
  let obrazky: Obrazky
  let dostupnost: Dostupnost   
}

struct Linky: Codable, Equatable {
  let program: String
  let ivysilani: String
}

struct Nazvy: Codable, Equatable {
  let nadtitul: String?
  let nazev: String
  let original: String?
  let nazev_casti: String?
}

struct Ikony: Codable, Equatable {
  let zvuk: Zvuk
  let ad: Bool
  let skryte_titulky: Bool
  let neslysici: Bool
  let live: Bool
  let premiera: Bool
  let cb: Bool
  let hvezdicka: Bool
  let labeling: String
  let puvodni_zneni: Bool
  let pomer: String
}

enum Zvuk: String, Codable {
  case M = "mono"
  case S = "stereo"
  case D = "duální zvuk"
    
  var description: String { rawValue }
}

struct Dostupnost: Codable, Equatable {
  let stav: String
  let od: String
  let `do`: String
}

struct Obrazky: Codable, Equatable {
  let tv_program: String
  let nahled: String
}
```

Program tag with attributes is for exact day and tv channel
it works as schedule.

, then comes Porad - a show
and it has XML tags
Linky - links and here comes another problem that Linky contains several tags:
one is  - it is just a link for showing the show online
and second one -  without attributes - it is another link for show, but its name is same as my root tag for whole day - The only difference is that one has attributes and one does not. But is can be solved inside

```
func parser(
  _ parser: XMLParser,
  didStartElement elementName: String,
  namespaceURI: String?,
  qualifiedName qName: String?,
  attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]
)
```

I need help how to create such complicated structure so I can use it in Views.

Thanks.

I hope I have explained it enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a three step process for this, **but it looks like you only need step 3**.

1. Convert the XML to JSON, using an online converter such as https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson …

```
{
  "program": {
    "porad": {
      "linky": {
        "program": "http://www.ceskatelevize.cz/porady/15560675929-rok-valky/223411033420224/",
        "ivysilani": "http://www.ceskatelevize.cz/ivysilani/15560675929-rok-valky/223411033420224/"
      },
      "vps": "A24020558",
      "datum": "2023-02-24",
      "cas": "05:59",
      "nazvy": {
        "nadtitul": "",
        "nazev": "Rok války",
        "original": "",
        "nazev_casti": ""
      },
      "dil": "",
      "zanr": "Zpravodajství",
      "stopaz": "181:00",
      "noticka": "Rok od ruské invaze na Ukrajinu. Rok, který změnil všední život v Česku. Události připomenou zpravodajové přímo ze zdevastované země, ale i Ukrajinci, kteří dočasně našli domov v České republice. Speciální vysílání ČT1 a ČT24",
      "regionalni": "N",
      "alternativa": "N",
      "ikonky": {
        "zvuk": "S",
        "skryte_titulky": 1,
        "neslysici": 0,
        "ad": 0,
        "live": 0,
        "premiera": 1,
        "cb": 0,
        "hvezdicka": 0,
        "labeling": "",
        "puvodni_zneni": 0,
        "pomer": "16:9",
        "hd": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) to create the `Codable` structs from the JSON

```
struct Program: Codable {
    let porad: [Porad]
}

struct Porad: Codable {
    let linky: Linky
    let vps: String
    let datum: String
    let cas: String
    let nazvy: Nazvy
    let dil: String
    let zanr: String
    let stopaz: String
    let noticka: String
    let regionalni: String
    let alternativa: String
    let ikonky: Ikonky
}

struct Ikonky: Codable {
    let zvuk: String
    let skryteTitulky: Int
    let neslysici: Int
    let ad: Int
    let live: Int
    let premiera: Int
    let cb: Int
    let hvezdicka: Int
    let labeling: String
    let puvodniZneni: Int
    let pomer: String
    let hd: Int
}

struct Linky: Codable {
    let program: String
    let ivysilani: String
}

struct Nazvy: Codable {
    let nadtitul: String
    let nazev: String
    let original: String
    let nazevCasti: String
}
```

3. Use https://github.com/CoreOffice/XMLCoder in the same way you would use a `JSONDecoder`, e.g.:

```
let data = // Data from XML
let decoder = XMLDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let program = try XMLDecoder().decode(Program.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Although I cannot use provided xml to json converter as I always read data in xml format. I wanted to learn how to do that manually, but I will try XMLCoder first.

Comment: I only use the XML to JSON converter to provide input to Quicktype, to create the Codable structs. In the app I read XML, and Decode using `XMLDecoder()`. It is a _lot_ of work to write your own XML parser, with lots of chances to getting it wrong.

Comment: Tested, but an error has appeared: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "ikony", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "porad", intValue: nil), XMLKey(stringValue: "0", intValue: 0), XMLKey(stringValue: "0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "ikony", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No attribute or element found for key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"ikony\", intValue: nil) (\"ikony\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: It was typo from my side...now it is working. Thank, I will now fight with ForEach to show all shows inside.

Comment: Just now  [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

Comment: Please ask in a new question